# Matplotlib 3d plot_wireframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw two plot_wireframe in a single figure. I am new to matplotlib.. I read the tutorial but still have some problems.

(1) How can I change the color of lines and add legend in the figure?

```
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
 ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z1)
 ax.legend("View window")  # not correct.
 ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z2)
 ax.legend("High window")
 plt.show()
```

(2) Another problem is that if I rotate the figure using mouse (in Win 7), it seems not updated until I resize the window.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the colour or adjust the legend label, set this directly in the plotting call:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z1, color='r', label='View window')
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z2, color='c', label='High window')
ax.legend()   # call this to actually show the legend; but use label above to set the text.
plt.show()
```

If you read the [documentation for plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), you'll see the dozens of options you can normally include to almost every plotting function in matplotlib, as well as the various linestyles and colours.

I don't know about the updating on rotation with the mouse; that may have to do with the drawing backend that matplotlib uses. If possible, you can try another backend and see if that works (a bit more on [backends](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend); no guarantee this will work).